# html. Как реализовать - при маштабировании сайта (ctrl + scroll) чтоб нужный блок оставался исходного размера?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

html. Как реализовать - при маштабировании сайта (ctrl + scroll) чтоб нужный блок оставался исходного размера?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var zoom = window.devicePixelRatio;
zoomChanged();    

// отлавливаем изменение зума
window.onresize = function() {
    var z = zoom;
    zoom = window.devicePixelRatio;
    if (z !== zoom){
        zoomChanged();
    }
}    

// накладываем антизум на нужный блок
function zoomChanged(){
    if (zoom === 1){
        neededBlock.style.zoom = '';
        return;
    }
    var antiZoom = Math.round(1 / zoom * 100000) / 100000;
    neededBlock.style.zoom =  antiZoom * 100 + '%';
}    


// P.S. transform:scale(x) xреново работает
```

Answer (score 1):

Стоит указывать все вместо `px` в `%`,например `width:10%`

Comment: Верстка не адаптивная. А нужный блок в % тогда будет зумиться не от маштабирования а от изменения размера окна, что не желательно